# How to insert file names into access table with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'd like some help ...
I have a sub from the access where I read all files with .gif extension in a certain folder and would like to know how to proceed to insert all the names that were read in an access table, I made the code below but it is not working ... can you help me?

```
Sub realAllFiles ()

Dim varFile As Variant
Dim CustomerFolder As String
Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog

.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Title = "Upload | Selecione a pasta de imagens capturadas..."
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "All files", "*.gif*"
.InitialFileName = "H:\Gestao de Dados Processamento\FAP\Baixa de Pendencia DUT\Novo Fluxo"

If .Show = True Then
      For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
         CustomerFile = varFile
      Next
      Else: Exit Sub
   End If
End With

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "MyTable", CustomerFile, False

End Sub
```

Comment: What does that mean `"it is not working"` - error messages? unanticipated behaviour?

Comment: You don;t have  table or the fields defined - I guess that would be a start

Comment: Read about the AddNew command using DAO recordsets - Docmd.Transfertext isn't going to work the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

The first approach is to set-up an import query passing the file name as parameter.

The query's SQL:

```
PARAMETERS [prmFileName] Text (255);
INSERT INTO T ( FieldName )  '<- Change to the actual table and field names
SELECT [prmFileName] As _FileName;
```

---

Then call the query inside the loop:

```
Sub realAllFiles()

    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim CustomerFolder As String
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Upload | Selecione a pasta de imagens capturadas..."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.gif*"
        .InitialFileName = "H:\Gestao de Dados Processamento\FAP\Baixa de Pendencia DUT\Novo Fluxo"
    End With

    If fDialog.Show = True Then
        For Each varFile In fDialog.SelectedItems
            With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("ImportQueryName") '<- change to the above query's name
                .Parameters("[prmFileName]").Value = varFile
                .Execute dbFailOnError
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

The second approach is through a recordset:

```
Sub realAllFiles()

    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim CustomerFolder As String
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("TableName") '<- change to the actual table name

    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Upload | Selecione a pasta de imagens capturadas..."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.gif*"
        .InitialFileName = "H:\Gestao de Dados Processamento\FAP\Baixa de Pendencia DUT\Novo Fluxo"
    End With

    If fDialog.Show = True Then
       For Each varFile In fDialog.SelectedItems
          rs.AddNew
          rs("Fieldname").Value = varFile '<- change to the actual field name
          rs.Update
       Next
    End If

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the recordset option and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot to everyone for the help.
Is the topic automatically closed?

Comment: Glad it's sorted. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers